# Contar resultados de um select no Kohana

Tags: php, kohana

Gostaria de saber como eu faço a contagem de resultados de um select no Kohana?
Eu tenho esse código:

```php
public function action_verification() {
    $login = $this->request->post('login');
    $senha = md5($this->request->post('senha'));
    //$result = ORM::factory('usuario')->where('login', '=', $login)->and_where('senha', '=', $senha)->find_all();
    $result = DB::select('*')
            ->from('usuarios')
            ->where('login', '=', $login)
            ->and_where('senha', '=', $senha)
            ->as_object()
            ->execute()
            ->current();
    $session = Session::instance();        
    if (count($result) == 0) {
        $session->set('erro', "Usuário ou senha incorreto!");
        $this->redirect('login');
    } else {
        if ($result->codCliente != 0) {                
            $session->set('nome', $result->login);
            $session->set('active',TRUE);
            $this->redirect('AdminHelpdesk/home');
        } else {
            $this->redirect('admin/home');
        }
    }
}
```

Só que ele sempre me retorna 1. Se eu deixar somente isso:

```php
$result = DB::select('*')
            ->from('usuarios')
            ->where('login', '=', $login)
            ->and_where('senha', '=', $senha)
            ->as_object()
            ->execute();
```

Aí sim ele me retorna 1 ou 0, só que fazendo dessa forma ele me resulta nesse erro:

> ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined property: Database_MySQL_Result::$codCliente

Ou seja, ele me da o erro nesse `if`:

```php
if ($result->codCliente != 0) {
```

Alguém pode me dar uma ajuda com isso?

Answer (score 1):

Tente isto após `$session = Session::instance();`

```
 var_dump($result);
```

E veja se $codCliente aparece setado, se não, para qual variável está sendo setado o Id resultante, provavelmente a id está setada com nome diferente entre o BD e o objeto.

Comment: O nome está o mesmo do BD, e o var_dumpe me mostra isso:

object(Database_MySQL_Result)[21]
  protected '_internal_row' => int 0
  protected '_query' => string 'SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE `login` = 'teste1@id.ftd.com.br' AND `senha` = 'e959088c6049f1104c84c9bde5560a13'' (length=112)
  protected '_result' => resource(80, mysql result)
  protected '_total_rows' => int 0
  protected '_current_row' => int 0
  protected '_as_object' => boolean true
  protected '_object_params' => null

Comment: O resultado está exibindo um objeto, `$result->result` é aonde está o resource, que é um tipo de retorno do mysql.
Quando você está chamando `count($result)`. Ele está aplicando diretamente no objeto, e não no retorno do mysql, o que não funciona.
Tente aplicar `count($result->result)`, se não der, tente verificar o que está armazenado neste result, modificando o `var_dump($result)` para `var_dump($result->result)`.

Comment: If ($result->num_rows > 0) {